# PHP: dom is missing from your system

Tags: laravel, dom, ini

Can you please help me, I am facing a trouble installing Laravel on my Ubuntu 18.04. When I run the commend `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my_app`, I get this error:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install php-xml extension for dom. If you are using a Debian based system, you can install via the command below.

`apt install php-xml`

Comment: It worked!! I am using Ubntu 18.04 but it finally worked. Thank you very much.